# How to change shape and fill of points in CAP (dbRDA)

Tags: r, plot, vegan

Why are the points still showing up inside the shapes? It makes it very hard to look at.  I want to change it so that the shapes look as they are in the legend. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
# Define Colors
colvec <- c("#000000", "#999933", "#661100", "#009e73","#f0e442", "#0072b2", "#d55e00", "#cc79a7", '#888888', '#6699CC')

# plot 
(ca <- capscale(co1 ~ Depth + Oxygen + Salinity  + POC, data = en, dist = "bray"))
plot(ca)
points(ca, display = "sites", col = colvec[en$Region], cex = 1.4, pch = 1:10)
with(ca, legend("topleft", legend=levels(en$Region), cex =1.4, col = colvec, pch = 1:10))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [plot.cca {vegan}](https://vegandevs.github.io/vegan/reference/plot.cca.html):

> The plot function sets colours (`col`), plotting characters (`pch`) and character sizes (`cex`) to certain standard values. For a fuller control of produced plot, it is best to call `plot()` with `type = "none"` first, and then add each plotting item separately using `text.cca` or `points.cca` functions. These use the default settings of standard text and points functions and accept all their parameters, allowing a full user control of produced plots.

Therefore, set `type = "none"` for setting frames only, and add custom points with `points()` afterward.

```r
plot(ca, type = "none")
points(ca, display = "sites", col = colvec[en$Region], cex = 1.4, pch = 1:10)
```